# RN - Change parents' screenProps

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm working on a React Native menu with a StackNavigator. If the user press a ListItem an id should be passed to all other Tabs in this menu, so the data can get fetched from an API. I tried to use `screenProps` to pass the data. Unfortunately I wasn't able to reset the value, when pressing a ListItem.

```
export default class Index extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <OrderScreen
          screenProps={ { Number: 123 } }
      />
    );
  }
}
```

In the child components I can access the prop but not reassign it:

```
export default class ListThumbnailExample extends Component
{
  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);
    const{screenProps} = this.props;
    this.state = { epNummer: screenProps.Number };
  }

  render()
  {
    return ( 
      <Content>
      <List>
      {
        this.state.orders.map(data => ( 
        <ListItem key = {data.Number}
          onPress = {() =>
            {
              this.props.screenProps.Number = data.Number;
              this.props.navigation.navigate('Orders')
            }
          }
          <Text>{ data.name }</Text> 
        </ListItem >
        ))
      }
      </List>  
    </Content >
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: screenProps is getting deprecated, I suggest you do not use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In React and React-native props are **immutable** by design :
https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#props-are-read-only

In your case if you want to pass screen-specific data you may wanna try passing them in the params of the navigation.navigate() function like this :

```
 this.props.navigation.navigate('Orders',data.Number)
```

you can then access them in "Orders" screen from : props.navigation.state.params

More information here : https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params.html